# How can I implement this using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to build a calendar-like interface for a hotel booking app as shown below. I'm not able to use any of the pub dev packages here because the leftmost column has to contain names of the Hotel rooms. Any ideas on how can this be implemented?

[The Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmf5G.png)

Comment: If my answer below is useful please take a second to accept it, or otherwise let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a [Table widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) would be a great way to solve this

Comment: Adding dates for every single column would be an extremely painful task. Don't you think?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could probably just use a datetime object to extract weekday and date. Start with datetime.now() for the first column, then datetime.now() + 1, +2, Etc, for the current week. Use a function to move relatively to today. Say user wants to show next week,  youd compute datetime.now()+7 (or datetime.now() + 7 * nb of times user pressed “next week”).

Comment: ...use a function call to generate the columns. I’m not on a computer now but I could write you a working example in a little bit if that’d be helpful??

Comment: It'll be really great if you could do that! Thanks a lot!